# How to "properly" format js core elements?

Tags: javascript, formatting

I've read a lot of articles on JavaScript formatting and the rules etc. But my question here is how to format core JavaScript elements (i.e. functions, arrays, and objects)

Usually for functions I use the following:

```
function myFunction(argument1 , argument2 , optionalargument3) {
    optionalargument3 === undefined ? optionalargument3 : "default value";
    return optionalargument1;
}
```

or:

```
var myFunction = function(argument1 , argument2 , optionalargument3) {
    optionalargument3 === undefined ? optionalargument3 : "default value";
    return optionalargument1;
}
```

but this is controversial. For objects I use:

```
var Car = {
    model        : undefined
    make         : "Sudan"
    MPG          : 7.5
    highway-mpg  : 11.5
};
```

of course, this is highly controversial and most people use different methods.
and for for loops, I use:

```
for(var i = 0; i < (array.length + 1); i++) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

People also seem to have devolved the idea to write out global in a list before objects or functions.

eg:

```
var winMessage = "You Win!";
var loseMessage = "Loser!";
var cash = 0;
var intrest = null;

function randomInteger(low , high) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random())*(high-low))+low
}
var Car = {
    model        : undefined
    make         : "Sudan"
    MPG          : 7.5
    highway-mpg  : 11.5
};
```

Are there any universal accepted, or a generically "proper" way to format your JavaScript code?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.+

Comment: @thefourtheye added an additional segment at the bottom to attempt and prevent that.

Comment: `var myFunction !== function myFunction`

Comment: Also, proper `for` loop (performance) `for (var i = 0, max = array.length; i < max; i += 1) {...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mostly down to preference but it is important to keep a consistent style throughout your code base particularly if you are working in a team to increase readability of your code.

You can either define your own style or adopt an existing one such as the Google style guide (https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml), or Crockfords (http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html).

JavaScript has automatic semi-colon insertion which means that some types of formatting can lead to code that doesn't work as intended such as the following where the interpreter will ignore the object literal because it will insert a semi-colon directly after the `return` keyword:

```
return
{
  name: "Foo"
};
```

In your example

> `optionalargument3 === undefined ? optionalargument3 : "default value";`

doesn't actually do anything because there is no assignment, but a nice clean way to deal with default arguments is instead of using

```
arg = arg === undefined ? "default value" : arg;
```

you can use the semantically identical and cleaner version:

```
arg = arg || "default value";
```